# Copying a value from a remote url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to copy a value from a remote website, lets say it is held in on www.example.com in a div with an id of exampleValue, is there any way to do this with php, javascript, or any other method?

Comment: Google is best way for searching...?

Comment: isn't `cURL` an option for this?

Comment: use file_get_contents then domdocument, then xpath, or use simple_html_dom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose to do it with PHP, you can read the HTML source using [file_get_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php), and then read the value of the `div` using `XPath` (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Something like:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
$value = $xpath->query("//div[@id='IdOfInterest']/text()");
```

Comment: Darn it you beat me :(

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, Use `file_get_contents` to grab the page HTML, then search it for the value you want.